# Antebellum State and Local Election Data

Tags: data-request, usa, elections

Is there data on voter turnout and election returns for state and local elections (gubernatorial, etc) during the 1840-1860 time period in the United States at the county level?

If no comprehensive or piecemeal dataset exists, I'd also be open to primary source references that would allow me to build such a dataset myself.

Comment: in Maryland, it's handled at the state level for all except municipal elections.  Unfortunately, they only have local election info back to the 1980s posted online : http://www.elections.state.md.us/elections/ .  (but back to 1948 for presidential elections)

Comment: Good luck! From what I've seen the openelections.net project try to deal with just collecting data back to 2000, I'm not optimistic that those kinds of records will turn up, at least at any scale.